# Will a nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) or magnetic resonance imaging (MRI) impulse blind our signal response sensor?

Tags: inductor, coil, magnetics, resonance, induction

[image]

After we send an impulse to the coil, when we start read the coil will have self oscillations. What influence will the self oscillations have on the read response? How can we deal with the self oscillation? Will the problem be worse if the Q is higher?

Comment: Won't the frequency of oscillation and its decay be affected by the sample under measurement hence, you can gain good information from it. I'm not in any way an expert on MRI btw. Maybe the sample under measurement will generate a totally different frequency that can be detected?

Comment: Presumably the self oscillations **are** the read response? If you want to pick up very small signals from Larmor procession, then you may have to blank your detector until the large signals have decayed.

Answer (score 0):

The ring-down of the coil is indistinguishable from the nuclear resonance signal. There is a trade-off between high Q (good sensitivity) and low Q (good bandwidth, and shorter dead-time). In any case, the ring-down time must be shorter than the coherence time of your sample.

If you can operate at higher frequencies, then, for the same Q, the ring-down time is shorter.